# Cucumber Java with Selenium - Runnable Method is missing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, bdd

I'm facing the next issue working with Cucumber in Maven project.
This is because I don't have a Runnable method for do this.
I was looking for information about, but it has been hard for me.

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory.createRunnerForTestWithParameters(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory.java:16)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.createRunnersForParameters(Parameterized.java:313)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

This is my Runner Cucumber Class:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features={"src/features/Login.feature"}
                 ,format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
                 ,glue = {"cucumber.CucumberStepDefs"}
)
/*@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        CucumberStepDefs.class,
})*/

public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

This is my Selenium/cucumber class:

```
import cl.chipacorp.test.SolutAutomatedWebTest;
import cl.chipacorp.util.data.SetDatos;
import cl.chipacorp.util.report.Report;
import cucumber.annotation.en.Given;
import cucumber.annotation.en.Then;
import cucumber.annotation.en.When;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

//JAVA

@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class CucumberStepDefs extends CoopeuchAutomatedWebTest {


    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
    public String usuario;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
    public String pass;


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Object[] data() {
        return SetDatos.getInstance().getData(CucumberStepDefs.class);
    }


    @Given("^Ingresar a la URL de Branch en ambiente QA$")
    public void Login() throws Exception {


        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        baseUrl = "http://brs1coreqa-01.coopeuch1.cl/";
        driver.get(baseUrl + "IBSBranchnet_COOPEUCH_Q5A/WebTeller.htm");
        driver.switchTo ().defaultContent ();
        driver.switchTo ().frame ("frmbody");
    }


    @When("^Se desplieguen los campos Username y Password, Ingresar las credenciales correspondientes$")
    public void UsuarioPass () throws Exception {

        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbTELLUSERID")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbTELLUSERID")).sendKeys(usuario);
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbUSERPASSW")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbUSERPASSW")).sendKeys(pass);

        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C01");

        driver.findElement(By.id("BtnSubmit")).click();
    }

    @Then("^Usuario accede a Branch con su correspondiente usuario$")
    public void Logout () throws Exception {
        driver.switchTo ().defaultContent ();
        driver.switchTo ().frame ("frmwebteller");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C02");

        driver.switchTo ().defaultContent ();
        driver.switchTo ().frame ("frmbody").switchTo ().frame ("menu"); //main - suboption0001

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b")).click();
        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C03");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Off")).click();
        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C04");

        //REPORTE NO BORRAR.
        Report.getInstance ().createReport (this, screenshot.getImages (),usuario);

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

By other hand, these are my POM dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-opera-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${appium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>${gherkin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have look for help, but I'm new in Cucumber.
Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Where you are passing ${junit.version} this variable in your pom

Comment: Why use Parameterized runner in the stepdefinition class? The error is from that class.

Comment: I'm using the Parameterized runner, because I have to get the data from a package that have a txt file and make sendKeys to some fields.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the `Cucumber` runner anymore. The `Parameterized` runner runs your test with a standard `BlockJunit4ClassRunner` for each set of parameters. Therefore it discovers test by looking for method with the `@Test` annotation which you don't have anymore.

What you want to do is using the `Parameterized` runner but let it internally use the `Cucumber` runner. Since JUnit 4.12 this is possible:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@UseParametersRunnerFactory(CucumberRunnerFactory.class)
public class CucumberStepDefs extends CoopeuchAutomatedWebTest {

    public static class CucumberRunnerFactor
            implements ParameterizedRunnerFactory {

        public Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(
            TestWithParameters test
        ) throws InitializationError {
            try {
                return Cucumber(test.getTestClass().getJavaClass());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new InitializationError(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Object[] data() {
        return SetDatos.getInstance().getData(CucumberStepDefs.class);
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
    public String usuario;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I already created a CucumberRunnerFactory.class, and a ParameterizedRunnerFactory.class, but I'm facing messages in red with the Cucumber of  return Cucumber(test.getTestClass().getJavaClass());

Comment: Hi Stefan: the return Cucumber is displayed in red and says: Cannot resolve method. I already created CucumberRunnerTest class and ParameterizedRunnerFactoty.

Comment: Are you using `cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber`? If yes can you please tell me the error.

Comment: Thanks for all, Stefan, but when I run the class it displays the next issues: java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class cl.cucumber.CucumberStepDefs

 at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersMethod(Parameterized.java:299)
 at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:246)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.